# Intersection of subspaces and dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $\{V_i\}$ be subspaces of $W$ with $\sum_{i=1}^r\dim(V_i)>(r-1)\dim(W)$. Show that $\bigcap_{i=1}^rV_i\ne\{0\}$

My Attempt:

Prove by induction on $r$ number of subspaces. Base case: $\dim(V_1)>0\implies V_1\ne\{0\}$. Inductive hypothesis, suppose this hold for any $r\le n$ subspaces. If $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\dim(V_i)>n\dim(W)$ then $\sum_{i=1}^n\dim(V_i)>(n-1)\dim(W)$ for any enumereation of $V_i$'s. So $\bigcap_{i=1}^rV_i\ne\{0\}$ for any $r\le n$ number of subspaces. Suppose $\bigcap_{i=1}^{n+1}V_i=\{0\}$.

How should I continue?

Answer (score 4):

I would try a different approach.

Let $W^*$ be the dual space to $W$, the set of linear functionals
on $W$. It has the same dimension as $W$. Let $V_i^\perp$ be the annihilator of $V_i$ in $W^*$, that is
$$V_i^\perp=\{f\in W^*:f(V_i)=\{0\}\}.$$
Then $\dim(V_i^\perp)=\dim (W)-\dim(V_i)$. Your condition
amounts to $\sum \dim(V_i^\perp)<\dim(W)$. This implies
$\dim(\sum V_i^\perp)<\dim(W)=\dim(W^*)$ and so $\sum V_i^\perp\ne W^*$.
Can you infer from this that $\bigcap V_i\ne\{0\}$?

Comment: Lord Shark's wonderful argument shows that, if $V_1,\dots,V_r$ are subspaces of a finite dimensional vector space $W$, then we have $$\dim\ \bigcap V_i\ge\sum\dim V_i-(r-1)\dim W,$$ and this inequality is sharp.